# Adding a document in an subcollection in an already existing document | Firebase v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add a document to a subcollection in an existing document (check code below). When the document is being updated, there is being added a completely new document with the same id, but the existing document is not updated. How can I add the following data below in the already existing document, instead of making a new one?

Code:

```
const docRef = doc(db, "users", data.id);
const colRef = collection(docRef, 'teams')
addDoc(colRef, {
   id: response.data.account.id,
   role: 'owner',
   uid: data.id,
});
```

[image: Firebase firestore]

Comment: My new document inside the subcollection is still getting added in a new document inside the users collection (the grey, italic name above).

Comment: Can you try `console.log(\`'${data.id}'\`)` and share the output? Just to ensure there isn't any trailing whitespace ?

Comment: You were correct! It was a small space before the id, I removed it and now it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @dharmaraj, the issue could be caused by a trailing whitespace  so a good way to check could be printing the `data.id` field using `console.log('${data.id}')`.

This was confirmed by the OP and after the fix everything worked.