# Why the firestore is duplicating documents with same id?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase to store some documents. I have created a document that has a subcollection named negotiations but when I try to add more documents to that subcollection it is duplicating the document (with the same ID):

[image: duplicated id]

How is that possible to create documents with same ID? How can I avoid that?

Comment: Please show us the paths to those documents.

Comment: You probably have one or more white spaces in the ID. As Alex indicated, you should look at the path by hovering the house icon in the Firestore console and click on the pen.

Comment: @leokury Have you checked the above comment and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65980438/18265638) by Renaud Tarnec, seems one of the ID have a trailing space also check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70906825/adding-a-document-in-an-subcollection-in-an-already-existing-document-firebase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, there is an extra blank space and I was able to see that by checking the path as indicated by Alex and Renaud. Thank you!

[image]